# Starting Tornado with Nginx on Ubuntu 10.04 automatically with domain name

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-10.04, tornado

I've managed to set up my nginx.conf file and it looks like this:

```
root       www www;


worker_processes 1;

worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {

  worker_connections  8000;

  accept_mutex off;

}

error_log  logs/error.log;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;

http {
  # Set the mime-types
  include       mime.types;

  # And the fallback mime-type
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  # Format for our log files
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  # Click tracking!
  access_log   logs/access.log  main;

  # ~2 seconds is often enough for HTML/CSS, but connections in
  # Nginx are cheap, so generally it's safe to increase it
  keepalive_timeout  5;

  # You usually want to serve static files with Nginx
  sendfile on;

  tcp_nopush on; # off may be better for Comet/long-poll stuff
  tcp_nodelay off; # on may be better for Comet/long-poll stuff

  # Enable Gzip
  gzip  on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_min_length 1100;
  gzip_buffers     4 8k;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/json;

  gzip_static on;

  gzip_proxied        expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_vary           on;

  server {
    # listen 80 default deferred; # for Linux
    # listen 80 default accept_filter=httpready; # for FreeBSD
    listen 80 default;

    # e.g. "localhost" to accept all connections, or "www.example.com"
    # to handle the requests for "example.com" (and www.example.com)
    server_name _;

    # Path for static files
    root /srv/www/example.com/public_html/src/static;

    expires 1M;

    # Static assets
    location ~* ^.+\.(manifest)$ {
      expires -1D;
      root   /srv/www/example.com/public_html/src/;
      access_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/static.logs;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(ico|ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
      # Only set expires max IFF the file is a static file and exists
      if (-f $request_filename) {
        expires max;
        root   /srv/www/example.come/public_html/src/static;
        access_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/static.logs;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My questions for nginx file is:
1) I would want to host my application with the domain name : www.example.com, which line of the nginx.conf file do i change?

My nginx.conf file is found in the same folder as app.py.

2) When I was trying to start nginx by typing /etc/init.d/nginx start, I received the following error message:

Error Message:

```
Starting nginx: [emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: still could not bind()
nginx.
```

I have not done any configuration to the nginx.conf file found at /etc/nginx
My questions for this part are:
3)  How do i fix the error? 
4) How do i start nginx automatically?

I've tried running my Tornado app by typing
python app.py
Than I navigate to http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8888 , and my app works correctly.

However, should I close my terminal ( killing the process ) , my tornado app is no longer active.

My question here is:
5) how do i start tornado app automatically?
6) How do i run tornado on a domain name?

Thank you all for your kind patience.

Best Regards.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, try cross-posting this to ServerFault

Comment: You need to give more information about the environment your working in; eg. which version of linux you have installed, which version of nginx/python, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1) Change the `server_name`.

2) You probably have Apache running.

3) Stop the service (using something like `service httpd stop`) and then start nginx.

4) Try the following commands:

```
$ chkconfig httpd off
$ chkconfig --add nginx
$ chkconfig nginx on
$ service nginx start
```

5) Look at using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org) for running python apps

6) Check out the [nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org) for information on [reverse proxying](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule); nginx handles requests to the domain and passes those requests to your tornado backend.

Answer (score 0):

about the error message: the same problem when using Ubuntu 11.10 , it seems that Opera occupy the port 80, so just modify the value.